# IIS and HttpListener (.NET) with windows authentication

Tags: iis, http, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a question about Windows authentication with IIS and HttpListener

I have the following setup (All installed in same Windows 8.1 box. No outside communication). All requests are sent as http://localhost/......

### IIS

ASP.Net web application authentication

```
Anonymous: Disabled 
Windows Authentication: Enabled
```

### .Net httpListener

running as a Service run as local System Account and Windows authentication enabled

```
this.httpListener = new HttpListener();
this.httpListener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

### UWP Application (Windows 8.1)

UWP Application is just like a web browser. It has WebView control to see web contents.

The following capabilities are enabled

- Enterprise Authentication
- Internet (Client)
- Location
- Private Networks (Client & Server)

### Problem

When I navigate from the uwp app to the IIS web app it is asking for the credentials by popping up Windows dialog box. This is annoying for the user experience perspective because user is logged in with same credentials. But When I access HttpListener it authenticates correctly and no credentials are required.

I also checked the requests through fiddler. Initial request is identical, but with next steps for IIS request, it is continuously asking for NTLM.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYHOMIHLoAMKAQGhDAYKKwYBBAGCNwICC........
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

**Initial Request/Response**

### IIS

**Request**

```
GET http://localhost/webapp_net/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 21:37:24 GMT
Content-Length: 6016
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

### HttpListener

**Request**

```
GET http://localhost/appman HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-NZ
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; WebView/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 21:37:18 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Does anyone have a similar experience or an explanation for this?

Comment: Feel free to ask questions if above is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have an explanation for this, you are attempting to achieve Single Sign On (SSO) using the negotiate / integrated windows authentication mechanism. This will not work with the Local Security Authority by itself. Negotiate attempts to first use Kerberos authentication, and falls back to NTLM if Kerberos is not configured. Kerberos is a windows authentication mechanism that requires a Key Distribution Center, which is provided by Microsoft's Active Directory for domain joined computers. SSO to an IIS server using integrated windows authentication can only be accomplished using the Kerberos protocol. NTLM is a challenge-response authentication mechanism, which will prompt for credentials on each request.

## Sources:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-logon-scenarios
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247021.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have one question. How is the HttpListener working ?

Comment: It actually doesn't look like it is working, at least as intended. Your post indicates a HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized response, if you are able to access resources through the HTTPListener it is most likely falling back to anonymous authentication.

Comment: yes in the description it is 401. then it is negotiating with keys in the following responses (not included in the description) and request and finally getting 200 response.

Comment: 1 Response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2018 00:27:55 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

Comment: 2nd request

GET http://localhost/AppMan/js/knockout-min.js HTTP/1.1
...
Authorization: Negotiate YHMGBisGAQUFAqBpMG.............

Comment: 2nd Response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYHOMIHLoAMKAQGhDAYK....

Comment: 3rd Request
GET http://localhost/AppMan/js/knockout-min.js HTTP/1.1....
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UT......
Host: localhost

Comment: 3rd Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 60354
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: oRswGaA....
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2018 00:27:56 GMT

Comment: See if this article will help at all, specifically look at the 'auth' tab in fiddler and see what is going on with IIS, also check and make sure the IIS configuration is in 'Kernel Mode' [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication/) Maybe the HTTPAPI is able to take cached NTLM credentials and IIS is not, from my experience I have never gotten IIS to do SSO windows authentication with NTLM, only kerberos.